# Degree of a regular function on an algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field and $G$ be an affine algebraic group. We
assume that $G$ is a $k$-subvariety of
$\operatorname{GL}(V) \subset \operatorname{End}(V)$ for appropriate vector space $V$
of dimension $d= \dim{V}$.
Let $k[G]$ be the coordinate ring of $G$.

Why and how is it possible to associate to every element
$P \in k[G]$ a degree $\operatorname{deg}(P)$?

Although the assomption $G \subset \operatorname{End}(V)$ implies
that $k[G]= k[X^iY^j \mathrel\vert 1 \le i,j \le d]/I$ is a
quotient of a polynomial ring with ideal $I=I(G)$, there is no reason
why it should be possible to associate a degree to an element
from $k[G]$.

But seemingly that's exactly what is done in the proof of
Proposition 4.6 (Chevalley) from the notes [Réseaux des groupes de Lie](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebenoist/prepubli/08m2p6ch1a13.pdf) by Yves Benoist
(page 38).

Note the script is writen in French and seemingly the notation
for degree of a $P \in k[G]$ is $d^{\circ} P$. But as I explained above
this definition make no sense (at least) to me as long as $k[G]$ is not isomorphic to
a polynomial ring.

Does somebody know what Benoist has in mind there?

Comment: Could one simply declare the degree of $P$ to be the degree of a minimal-degree representative in $k[\operatorname{End}(V)]$?  It seems that all that is needed in the proof of Proposition 4.6 is a filtration of $I(\mathbf H)$.

Comment: The main point is that any finite-dimensional subspace of a representation of a linear algebraic group is contained in a finite-dimensional representation.  (The same trick is used to prove that every linear algebraic group embeds faithfully in some $\operatorname{GL}_n$.)  This is proven in a more Hopf-algebraic way in, for example, Proposition 1.9 of Borel's [Linear algebraic groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0941-6).